# Can't Google auth with multiple accounts

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, authentication, google-chrome-extension, google-authentication

I am trying to use the google apis with multiple users in my chrome extension. 
The main problems are: 
1) If I'm not logged in into browser I can't auth with google 
2) If I login in browser and then try to log in to the app, then autorisoes under that account and in chrome, no matter what account I chose in the menu.

Function `toggleGetIdTokenListener` invoked from the *background*.

```
export const toggleGetIdTokenListener = () => {
  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request) => {
    if (request.type === 'get_idToken') {
      getTokenId();
    }
  });
};

const createRequestURL = () => {
  const manifest = chrome.runtime.getManifest();

  const clientId = encodeURIComponent(manifest.oauth2.client_id);
  const scopes = encodeURIComponent(manifest.oauth2.scopes.join(' '));
  const redirectUri = encodeURIComponent('urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob:auto');

  const url = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth' +
    '?client_id=' + clientId +
    '&response_type=id_token' +
    '&access_type=offline' +
    '&redirect_uri=' + redirectUri +
    '&scope=' + scopes;

  return url;
};

const getTokenId = () => {
  chrome.tabs.create({
    url: createRequestURL(),
    active: false
  }, getResponseFromGoogle);
};

const getResponseFromGoogle = (authenticationTab) => {
  const RESULT_PREFIX = ['Success', 'Denied', 'Error'];

  // After the tab has been created, open a window to inject the tab
  chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function googleAuthorizationHook(tabId, changeInfo) {
    const titleParts = changeInfo.title.split(' ', 2);
    const result = titleParts[0];
    if (titleParts.length === 2 && RESULT_PREFIX.indexOf(result) >= 0) {
      chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(googleAuthorizationHook);
      chrome.tabs.remove(tabId);

      const response = titleParts[1];

      chrome.identity.getAuthToken({'interactive': true}, function (token) {
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
          console.log('ERROR', chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
          return;
        }

        const x = new XMLHttpRequest();
        x.open('GET', 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json&access_token=' + token);
        x.onload = function () {
          populateUserData(JSON.parse(x.response), response);
        };
        x.send();
      });
    }
  });

  createPopupWindow(authenticationTab)
};

const createPopupWindow = (authenticationTab) => {
  chrome.windows.create({
    tabId: authenticationTab.id,
    type: 'popup',
    focused: true
    // incognito, top, left, ...
  }, function () {
    chrome.tabs.update(authenticationTab.id, {'url': createRequestURL()});
  });
};

const populateUserData = (userInfo, id_token) => {
  const userData = [{
    name: userInfo.name,
    email: userInfo.email,
    id_token: id_token.substring(id_token.indexOf('=') + 1, id_token.indexOf('&')),
    clientId: '711602808537-cv3p6pe7hc2lvmo88ri0oti0rcqcme7a.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    picture: userInfo.picture
  }];

  connector.init();
  getUserFromServer(userData);
};
```

Any ideas? Thanks anyway!

Comment: What error are you encountering?

Comment: there was no errors. Its just logged in with chrome user